# sqlalchemy session.query oddity - double escape

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a table of file information in my DB, and I am trying to query and return the file_path column of the result as list of string.

My code looks like below

```
path_found = session.query(db.file_table.path).filter([filters]).all()
```

It returns a list of sqlalchemy.util._collections.result instead of list of string.  So I made the conversion using following line

```
result = [str(path) for path in path_found]
```

However, something really strange happens with that. If I access the path like "path_found[0].path" notation, backslashes in the file path is escaped once like;

```
"\\Users\\Public\\current\\1.PNG"
```

, but if I use the conversion and use line result[0], the backslashes are escaped twice so I get something like;

```
"\\\\Users\\\\Public\\\\current\\\\1.PNG".
```

I used  brute force to remove extra backslashes;

```
result[0].replace('\\\\', "\\")
```

Is there better way to handle this situation, possibly preventing double escaping to begin with?

Comment: Are you sure you're doing the right list comprehension? Don't you need `result = [path.path for path in path_found]`?

Comment: OMG, what lack of sleep does to a person.
Thank you so much for waking me up.
Could you please move your comment to the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're doing the right list comprehension? Don't you need `result = [path.path for path in path_found]`?